# How to Create an array menu? I have been giving a task to create a bank in C# but I am stuck right now

Tags: c#

This is how my current code looks like, I have been trying to make is so that I you will be able to transfer and withdraw money from each account but I have been unable since I wanna code the money in a array. Could anyone help me out?

using System;

namespace Individuellt_Projekt
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
        string[,] users = new string[5, 3];
        int index = 0;
       
        
        // First user
        users[0, 0] = "Filip Oldin"; //set username
        users[0, 1] = "hemlis123"; //set password
        users[0, 2] = "24"; //set age

        // Second user
        users[1, 0] = "Anna Holgersson"; //set username
        users[1, 1] = "hemlis1234"; //set password
        users[1, 2] = "54";
        // Third user
        users[2, 0] = "Tobbe Rikardsson"; //set username
        users[2, 1] = "hemlis12345"; //set password
        users[2, 2] = "43";

        users[3, 0] = "Kent Käll"; //set username
        users[3, 1] = "hemlis123456"; //set password
        users[3, 2] = "32";

        users[4, 0] = "Eva Hobert"; //set username
        users[4, 1] = "hemlis1234567"; //set password
        users[4, 2] = "19";



        Console.WriteLine("Hej och välkommen till AB Banken");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Huvudmeny");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ett ditt användarnam");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ett ditt lösenord");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();


        if (checkLogin(username, password))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Du är inloggad!");
            Console.WriteLine("Hej och välkommen till din kontomeny");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fel inloggning, försök igen");
            
        }



        static bool checkLogin(string username, string password)
        {

            if (username == "Filip Oldin" && password == "hemlis123")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (username == "Anna Holgersson" && password == "hemlis1234")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (username == "Tobbe Rikardsson" && password == "hemlis12345")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (username == "Kent Käll" && password == "hemlis123456")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (username == "Eva Hobert" && password == "hemlis1234567")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        bool since = true;
        while (since)
        {
             
            int accou;
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(" Skriv in en siffra till den del av kontot du vill till ");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Se dina konton och saldo ");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Överföring mellan konton ");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Ta ut pengar ");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Logga ut ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            accou = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            // int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //skriv alternativ
            switch (accou)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Saldo på lönekonto:  "); //<== money in account 
                    Console.WriteLine("Saldo på sparkonto: "); //<== money in account 
                    Console.WriteLine("Saldo på semesterkonto: "); //<== money in account 

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine(" Tryck på enter för att återgå till huvudmenyn");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("  Överföring mellan konton"); //<== Transfer money in account 
                    Console.WriteLine("  semesterkonto"); //<== money in account 
                    Console.WriteLine("  sparkonto");//<== money in account 
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine(" Tryck på enter för att återgå till huvudmenyn");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Ta ut pengar"); //<== Withdraw money in account 
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine(" Tryck på enter för att återgå till huvudmenyn");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Logga ut");
                    break;
               
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Ogiltig svar, försök igen");
                    since = false;
                    break;

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    
}
```

}

Comment: You should write a CLASS to hold the Name, Password, Age, and Balance, then create instances and store them in a `List<YourClassName>` (or an Array if you must). Using Arrays the way you are is a horrible design.

Comment: The productive answer here is that you really need to look at Object Oriented Programming (OOP). This is much broader than can be explained in a single answer here. You will be better off finding a course or tutorial on the subject.

Comment: Please also note that in `checkLogin` you should definitely check if the *stored* login matches the *stored* password, instead of hardcoding initial values.

Comment: Since this is obviously homework I think you should include the detail of the actual assignment, and what topics and structures you have been covering. A proper solution would involve object oriented programming, but if you have not covered such things it might not be the solution that is intended.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do like this.

```
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

List<User> users = new List<User>();

User u = new User();
u.Name = "Filip Oldin";
u.Password = "hemlis123";
u.Age = 24;
users.Add(u);

User u2 = new User();
u2.Name = "Anna Holgersson";
u2.Password = "hemlis1234";
u2.Age = 54;
users.Add(u2);

..........
static bool CheckLogin(string userName, string password)
{
    foreach (User userObject in users)
    {
        if(username == userObject.Name && password == userObject.Password)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And also add a field to the class to hold the current bank account balance.